# Query to show which manager has the most employees

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL server management studio, and need to find which manager has the most employees.

I want the output to show John Wick as highest

```
EmployeeID |  Numberofemployees
-------------------------------
    1      |         4

CREATE TABLE Employee (
enmployeeID int PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
JobTitle varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Manager int,
);

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 'John', 'Wick', 'Manager', 2)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2, 'Danny', 'Glover', 'Chairman', NULL)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (3, 'Sam', 'Smith', 'Manager', 2)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (4, 'Denise', 'Richards', 'Agent', 3)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (5, 'Tanner', 'Jones', 'Agent', 3)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (6, 'Danie', 'Wide', 'Admin', 1)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (7, 'Sue', 'Hobs', 'Admin', 1)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (8, 'Tommy', 'Laker', 'Accounts', 1)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (9, 'Clarence', 'Kennedy', 'Admin', 1)
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT Count(employeeID), Manager
From Employee
HAVING COUNT (Manager)=( 
SELECT MAX(Manager)
Group By employeeID
```

Comment: Assuming you want to count all subordinates down the managerial hierarchy, you will need to use a recursive CTE for this.  If you are only interested in how many people are directly managed by that employee, you will need a self join.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your data could you please try the following query

```
 SELECT TOP 1 X.Manager,X.CNTT
  FROM
   (
      SELECT E.MANAGER,COUNT(E.enmployeeID)CNTT
      FROM Employee AS E
      GROUP BY E.Manager 
   )X ORDER BY X.CNTT DESC
```

Comment: Amazing Sergey, this is very new to me. I never knew top 1 could be used like this

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT man.employeeID
       , man.FirstName
       , man.LastName, COUNT(*) AS countEmployees
       , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
   FROM Employee AS emp
   INNER JOIN Employee AS man ON emp.Manager = man.employeeID
   GROUP BY man.employeeID, man.FirstName, man.LastName
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a0f8bb648e7499ed699edeaeb313889)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

```
SELECT TOP 1 b.lastName,count(*) as numberOfEmployees FROM Employee as a 
        LEFT JOIN Employee as b ON a.Manager=b.employeeID
        -- LEFT JOIN Employee as c ON b.Manager=c.employeeID
        WHERE b.JobTitle='Manager'
        GROUP BY b.LastName
        ORDER BY numberOfEmployees DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution recurses down the hierarchy and counts up all employees, even employees of lower level managers

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT E.enmployeeID, E.MANAGER
      FROM Employee AS E
      JOIN Employee AS M ON M.enmployeeID = E.MANAGER
      WHERE M.JobTitle = 'Manager'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT E.enmployeeID, E.MANAGER
      FROM Employee AS E
      JOIN cte ON cte.enmployeeID = E.MANAGER
)
 SELECT TOP (1) Manager,COUNT(*)
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY Manager 
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```